# How do I Convert categorical columns into numerical ones that have multiple values in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the following columns into numerical values but I am stuck. I am not sure how to use pandas apply method when the column has multiple values.

`from seaborn import load_dataset`

`dfdi = load_dataset("diamonds")` 
`dfdi`

There are three values that have categorical data
`dfdi.cut.value_counts().sort_index()`
Ideal        21551
Premium      13791
Very Good    12082
Good          4906
Fair          1610
Name: cut, dtype: int64

`dfdi.color.value_counts().sort_index()`
D     6775
E     9797
F     9542
G    11292
H     8304
I     5422
J     2808
Name: color, dtype: int64

`dfdi.clarity.value_counts().sort_index()` 
IF       1790
VVS1     3655
VVS2     5066
VS1      8171
VS2     12258
SI1     13065
SI2      9194
I1        741
Name: clarity, dtype: int64

I am able to convert if it was binary. I tried to put an elif but I was getting an incorrect syntax error

`dfdi.cut = dfdi.cut.apply(lambda x: 5 if x == "Ideal" else 0)`

Tried but failed elif
`dfdi.cut = dfdi.cut.apply(lambda x: 5 if x == "Ideal" elif 4 if x == "Premium" elif 3 if x == "Very Good" elif 2 if x == "Good" else 1)`

I think a nested lambda would work here, but I am not sure on the syntax

Comment: Use LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder from sklearn. Or if you just want to use pandas, use pd.get_dummies function

Answer (score 0):

A `map` is what you need:

```py
df["cut"] = df["cut"].map({
    "Ideal": 5,
    "Premium": 4,
    "Very Good": 3,
    "Good": 2,
    "Fair": 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ds = dict(zip(df["cut"].unique().tolist(), [5,4,3,2,1]))
df["cut"].apply(lambda x: ds[x])
```

simply, use a dictionary...:)
create a dictionary that key is all unique values and value is your desired value.
and ternary operator in python is like:

```
data = value1 if condition1 else value2 if condition2 else value3
```

not elif... use a new ternary in else part